# Will installing Android Studio conflict with an existing installation of Unity with the Android sdk/ndk installed

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

When installing Unity, if you choose, it also installs the sdk/ndk for Android.

[image]

I want to separately install Android Studio for non gaming courses i'm doing.

Is the Unity installation of the android sdk isolated to the Unity installation folders. Or are there global paths and variables that the installation changes.

Wondering whether installing Android Studio separately will conflict with the Unity installation of the sdk (or vice versa).

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I use both Android Studio and Unity. I installed Android Studio before Unity. I have never encountered a problem such as conflicting SDK paths. You can also manually change the path to Android SDK in Unity.